# t:commandLink does not respond

Tags: java, jsf

I wrote the following code

```
<t:commandLink id="parameterYSubmit" action="#{parameters.updateParameterY}" onclick="if(!confirmit()) return false;">
    <h:outputText value="#{msgs['button.save']}" />
</t:commandLink>
```

I pressed on the command link, the popup open, I click ok and nothing accrue.
I have all the right beans and the functions.

Comment: It seems that `confirmit()` returns `false` all the time ??? not sure, try `if(!confirmit()){ return false;}else{return true;}`

Comment: What if you try without onclick="if(!confirmit()) return false;"? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i wrote

```
<form...
```

and not

```
<h:form...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `t:commandLink` its a inner tag of myFaces tags. So maybe this tag is not in MyFaces tag.